# Default copy constructor and assignment operator

Tags: c++, class, c++11, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

If among the elements of my class I have also a const data member, how do copy constructor and assignment operator behave?
I think, but I am not sure, that copy constructor is provided (as most cases) while assignment operator is not provided (differently from what happens normally) and so if I want to use it, I must implement it (of course not assigning the const data member)

Comment: A const member can happily be copy-constructed. Roughly, member constness starts being enforced at the opening brace of the constructor, but not in the initializer list (even const members need to be initialized to some value). Assignment operator simply won't be implicitly declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct foo {
  int const x;
};

foo f0{3}; // legal
foo f1 = f0; // legal, copy-construction

foo make_foo(int y) { return {y}; } // legal, direct-initialization

foo f2 = make_foo(3); // legal, elision and/or move-construction

f2 = f1; // illegal, copy-assignment
f2 = make_foo(3); // illegal, move-assignment
```

Construction and assignment are different operations.  `=` does not mean assignment always.

You can construct `const` subobjects; you cannot assign to them.  This property then applies to the object itself in its automatically written special member functions.